# Construct a CFG for

Tags: context-free-grammar, formal-languages

L1 = { a^i b^j | i,j>=0 }

My attempt:

```
S = SA|e

A = aAB|e

B = bB|e
```

I have no way to confirm my answer, is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not correct because there's no way to get a single "b" (or any number of "b"s without any "a"s).

(And I think you can fix it by changing just one letter ;o)

PS Sorry for earlier incorrect reply; thought it was for i=j.

Comment: so its correct for i!=j? Also, can you also quick confirm one more for L2={a^2n b^n ,n>=0} is {S=ASB|e}{A=A|aa|e}{B=b|e}? stack wot let me post another ques 'cuz I'm a newb!

Comment: no, it's not correct for i!=j - see the argument.  it cannot produce "b".  my "sorry" is about an earlier answer that i deleted (i was worried you might have read before i deleted it).  your L2 is also incorrect - it could be much simpler (no need for A and B at all).  for example, L2 can give S -> ASB -> aaSB -> aaB -> aa.

Comment: ok sorry for misreading your sorry in that case. And thanks I get it now for L1. But for L2, is my answer not correct because it has to be in its simplest form or does it not produce correctly?

Comment: i give an example where L2 does not produce correctly at the end of my previous comment.

Comment: almost! (it works but is not simplest) what is the first "S" for?  S->S->S is pointless.

Answer (score 1):

You define L1 = {a^i b^j | i, j >= 0}. In words, this is the language of all strings which begin with zero or more a's, and which end with zero or more b's. This is a regular language; a regular expression for it is a*b*. A regular grammar (also a context-free grammar) is the following:

```
S := lambda | aS | bT
T := lambda | bT
```

Another context-free grammar is the following:

```
S := lambda | aS | Sb
```

Sorry if I'm missing something and your language is more complicated than what I'm reading. If you have some reason to believe that L1 so defined is different from the language I have described, please explain.

Comment: Thanks! I get that my answer wasn't producing any b's without producing a's. And I tried to solve it again and got {S:=lambda|ASB} {A:=lambda|a} {B:=lambda|b} but it's still different from your solution but is it only because your's is a simplified version or did I get it wrong on second attempt as well? And it's not complicated, it really is that simple. I'm learning it fresh.