# Parts of context free grammar a big mystery

Tags: context-free-grammar

This is a homework question but I wouldn't ask here if it weren't vital for me to understand the question as soon as possible.

I have been given a language { w in {a,b}* | w is of the form a^n b^m y, where |y| = n+m } for which I have to make a context free grammar.

I think the problem lies in my understanding the problem, for my solution (my best guess):

S -> aS | bB | _      ("_" means empty)

B -> bBy

produces errors like "string 'aaaaba' could not be generated using your grammar" and such. Could someone help me to the right tracks? Apparently I'm not even supposed to write the 'y' at all, so what is its function? I've tried looking for examples on the web but have found none which would have a |x = z + k etc. in them.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Construct a CFG for](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406382/construct-a-cfg-for)

Comment: It's close, but there is the additional y at the end of the formula, which function is a mystery (a^n b^m y?). Thank you, though.

Answer (score 1):

The final `y` must contain as many letters as you produced for the a<sup>n</sup>b<sup>m</sup> part, so you need to also produce a letter after the nonterminal.

```
S -> aSa | aSb | B
B -> -- well, I'll leave a bit of the homework to you
```

Answer (score 0):

The notation is a bit bizarre, but I'm assuming that your language is the set of all strings consisting of some number of `a`s, then some number of `b`s, then a number of `a`s and/or `b`s equal to the total number of `a`s and `b`s in the first two parts.

If this is correct, then your existing grammar has a couple problems. First, the productions for `S` aren't going to ensure that you maintain a balance between the characters in the first two parts and the ones in the third part. Second, `B` will never resolve into a sequence of terminal symbols; it will grow forever without bound.

If I've got the language wrong, correct me.

Comment: Clarification on how I'm reading it: I think `y` is supposed to be the third part (that is, the one whose length is equal to the sum of the previous two). The part that says "w in {a,b}*" is why I'm assuming that it consists only of `a`s and `b`s. In this case, `y` will not correspond to a symbol in your context-free grammar, because you wouldn't be able to tell how long it has to be.